# Scrolling on page not working

Tags: jquery, mobile, scroll

I have this page below that for the life of me I can't get the scrolling to work on the iPhone. I've tried several types of different techniques and I can't get it to work. Any suggestions would be appreciated. It's jquery mobile.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="ui-mobile">
   <head>
      <style type="text/css">@media print {  .gmnoprint {    display:none  }}@media screen {  .gmnoscreen {    display:none  }}</style>
      <base href="http://ha.com/calendartoporig.html" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no" />
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png" />
      <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/9/12/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="../../codebase/dhtmlxscheduler_mobile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
      <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s.sharethis.com/loader.js"></script>-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/jquery.mobile-1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../_assets/css/jqm-docs.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../codebase/dhtmlxscheduler_mobile.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="applemartinigreen.css" />
      <script src="jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="../../../experiments/themeswitcher/jquery.mobile.themeswitcher.js"></script>
      <script src="../../_assets/js/jqm-docs.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
      <script src="mi.js"></script>
      <script src="Footer.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.css" />
      <script src="jQuery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js"></script>
      <script src="stay_standalone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <title>Event Home</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- InviteMakingView -->
      <div data-role="page" data-theme="g" id="eventhome" />
      <div data-role="content" style="padding: 0px">
         <div class="nav-glyphish-example ui-navbar" data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top" data-theme="g" role="navigation">
            <ul class="ui-grid-d">
               <li class="ui-block-a">
                  <a id="home" href="index.php" data-ajax="false" data-theme="g" data-icon="home" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-iconpos="top" data-inline="true" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-g ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-top"><span class="ui-btn-text">
                  Happening
                  </span></a>
               </li>
               <li class="ui-block-c">
                  <a id="friends" href="friendshome.html" data-ajax="false" data-theme="g" data-icon="custom" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-iconpos="top" data-inline="true" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-g ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-top"><span class="ui-btn-text">
                  People
                  </span></a>
               </li>
               <li class="ui-block-d">
                  <a id="companies" href="companyhome.html" data-ajax="false" data-theme="g" data-icon="custom" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-iconpos="top" data-inline="true" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-top ui-btn-up-g"><span class="ui-btn-text">
                  Places
                  </span></a>
               </li>
               <li class="ui-block-e">
                  <a id="invites" href="eventhome.php" data-ajax="false" data-theme="g" data-icon="custom" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist ui-btn ui-btn-up-g ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-top" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-iconpos="top" data-inline="true"><span class="ui-btn-text">
                  Parties
                  </span></a>
               </li>
               <li class="ui-block-b">
                  <a id="me" href="me.html" data-ajax="false" data-theme="g" data-icon="custom" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-iconpos="top" data-inline="true" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-g ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-top"><span class="ui-btn-text">
                  Me
                  </span></a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div>
         </div>
         <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-f">
               <div id="eventsetup" class="ui-block-b">
                  <div id="eventdetails">
                     <form action="evententry.php" method="post" data-ajax="false">
                        <p>
                           <b>
                           Event Name: <input id="evententry" type="text" name="eventname" />
                           </b>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                           <b>
                           <input id="evententry" type="hidden" name="companyname" value="<?= $fgmembersite->UserEmail() ?>" />
                           </b>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                           <b>
                           <input id="evententry" type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?= $fgmembersite->UserID() ?>" />
                           </b>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                           <b>
                           Start Date:  <input id="evententry" type="date" name="sdate" id="date" value="" />
                           </b>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                           <b>
                           End Date:  <input id="evententry" type="date" name="edate" id="date" value="" />
                           </b>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                           <b>
                           Time:  <input id="evententry" type="text" name="eventtime" />
                           </b>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                           <b>
                           Location: <input id="evententry" type="text" name="eventlocation" />
                           </b>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                           <b>
                           Dress Code: <input id="evententry" type="text" name="eventdress" />
                           </b>
                        </p>
                        <div id="footerSlideContainereh">
                           <div id="caltoolbar" data-tap-toggle="false" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="g">
                              <a id="refreshme" data-icon="custom" data-role="button" data-transition="fade" data-theme="g" onclick="location.reload()">
                              </a>
                              <input id="eventsub" type="submit" value="Enter Event" />
                     </form>
                     </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. There was some js code in the scheduler that was effecting the native scrolling. I removed those pieces of code, problem solved. Thanks